# Android PayPal Android SDK, Cardholder's name

Tags: android, paypal

Good morning developers

I'm facing the problem to intergrate PayPal API into my application.

The main purpose to post here is to ask about how to generate cardholder's name from PayPal Payment UI.

I just noticed that when I triggered credit-card payment method,

PayPal does not require any cardholder's name, just card number, expire date and CVV.

I have searched how to activate cardholder's name for hours and could not find anything from not only PayPal official API and also from stack overflow..

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to capture cardholder's name with RESTful APIs as instructed [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/), but not in Mobile SDK at this point. The method is not included with native MSDK yet.